# nginx fails to update after upgrade to 16.04 server

Tags: server, updates, 16.04, nginx

I upgraded from 14.04 server to 16.04 server.  I have always used the official nginx packages, because I needed support for things like SPDY and HTTP2 which were not in the 14.04 version of nginx.  Now when I try to update, I get the following error message.

```
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.11.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.11.1-1~xenial) over (1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.11.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html', which is also in package nginx-common 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.11.1-1~xenial_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
```

In my sources.list file I have:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will likely fix it. I had this, and a couple of other problems myself.

1. Move to /etc and copy the nginx directory for safety:

   ```
   cd /etc
   cp -R nginx/ nginx-bak/
   ```
2. Remove the old version of nginx:

   ```
   apt-get remove nginx nginx-common
   ```
3. Install the new nginx:

   ```
   apt-get install nginx
   ```
4. Answer no to any prompts to overwrite configs.
5. To enable and run nginx:

   ```
   systemctl unmask nginx.service
   systemctl start nginx.service
   ```

Comment: I had already figured this out, but it works... I don't think you need to destroy  /etc  I was running a production server, so the trick for me was `apt-get remove nginx-common`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "destroy /etc". I suggested no such thing. But as long as you have now fixed it - good.